# WinJS - UWP - Listview Item Reorderable not working in windows phone 10

Tags: uwp

I am working on UWP app with WinJS platform. I am working on Item Reorder feature in ListView. It is working fine in Windows 10 (Desktop and Tablet) but it is not working in Windows 10 Phone(Using windows phone 10 Preview as official version has not launched yet). When i try to hold any item in ListView , it eventually drops back and i'm not able to drag. Does anyone have any workaround here which can help.

I'm using code snippet below:

```
<div id="listView"
             class="win-selectionstylefilled"
             data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
             data-win-options="{
                itemDataSource: myData.dataSource,
                selectionMode: 'none',
                itemTemplate: smallListIconTextTemplate,
                itemsReorderable : true,
                layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }
            }">
        </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the HTML5 API of drag and drop is not supported on W10 phone, so the drag and drop is not supported on the WinJS ListView. If you want to do this, you have to use a library like [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula)

Comment: Hi Mehdi Lahlou,

Thanks for the information. so in  uwp i need to write a separate html/js for phone and desktop. 
I will try the alternate solution you have given.

Comment: No, in my app, i use dragula for both desktop and phone. I really do not like the ListView :)

Comment: Does this dragula library works fine on Data Virtualization?
For example: If there are 1000 items into listview. So in that all the items into the listview will occupy memory or  just the items into the current screen will occupy the memory?